# Angularjs: a Service that serves multiple $resource urls / data sources?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have an Angular service/provider that serves json data to my controller which works great:

```
    angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
      factory("statesProvider", function($resource){
      return $resource('../data/states.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
      });
    });
```

**But** I also need to serve json data to the same controller from another file `counties.json`.

Where can I find out how to I write a service that serves both files to my controller?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can update service to return a hash of resources, not a single one:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory("geoProvider", function($resource) {
    return {
      states: $resource('../data/states.json', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
      }),
      countries: $resource('../data/countries.json', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }
      })
    };
  });
```

You will be able to use it adding `.query()` at the end your function name i.e. `geoProvider.states.query()` and `geoProvider.countries.query()` and `myApp.services` has to be injected into your controller, then inject `geoProvider` service into controller itself as well.

Comment: This looks like what I am searching for but can you explain how to call "states" and "countries" from the controller? Normally, I would just do myApp.services.query(). Thanks

Comment: @chapstick In order to use it you should inject `myApp.services` module into module that contains controller, then inject `geoProvider` service into controller itself. After you'll be able to use `geoProvider.states.query()` and `geoProvider.countries.query()` in the controller

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you want to execute some code when both files have loaded.   Promises work really well for this.  I don't think resources return promises, but you can use the $http service for simple ajax calls.

Here I define one service each for the two data files, and a third service that returns a promise that gets fulfilled when both files are done loading.

```
factory('states',function($http) {
    return $http.get('../data/states.json');
}).
factory('countries',function($http) {
    return $http.get('../data/countries.json');
}).
factory('statesAndCountries', function($q, states, countries) {
    return $q.all([states, countries]);
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
statesAndCountries.then(function(data) {
    var stateData = data[0];
    var countryData = data[1];
    // do stuff with stateData and countryData here
});
```