# Multiple Factories/Rest paths for Angular JS 1.5 Spring MVC web app

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I've reviewed these postings as they are similar but they gave me no help how to solve my problem probably because I'm very new to Angular and Spring:

- [AngularJS: Creating multiple factories for every endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233481/angularjs-creating-multiple-factories-for-every-endpoint)
- [Angularjs: a Service that serves multiple $resource urls / data sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160771/angularjs-a-service-that-serves-multiple-resource-urls-data-sources)
- [Can I have multiple functions in my AngularJS Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821150/can-i-have-multiple-functions-in-my-angularjs-factory)

The first page of my web app that everyone logs into and sees lists all the properties listed by the realty company. I want to modify this so that they only see their properties.

The angular controller is

```
angular.module('communitypropApp').controller('DashboardController,function($rootScope,$scope,$state,CommunityProperties){
$scope.$state=$state;
$scope.communityProperties=[];

$scope.loadAll=function(){
CommunityProperties.query(function(result){
$scope.communityProperites=result.content;
});
});

$scope.loadall();
});
```

Inside my CommunityPropertiesRestController.java file I have

```
import . . . 
@RestController
@RestMapping("/rest/api")
public class CommunityPropertiesRestController(
@Inject 
CommunityPropertyDataService communityPropertiesDataService;
@PostMapping(value="/communityProperties",produces=MediaType.Application_Json_value)
public ResponseEntity<Void> create{
. . . 
}

@GetMapping(value="/communityProperties/{id}",produces=MediaType.Application_Json_value)
public ResponseEntity<CommunityProperties> get(@PathVariable Long id, User user)
CommunityProperties communityProperties=communityPropertiesDataService.getCommunityPropertiesById(id);
return Optional.OfNullable(communityProperties.map(. . . )
}

@GetMapping(value = "/communityProperties",produces = MediatType.Application_Json_value) 
. . . 
} 
. . . (I added)
@GetMapping(value="/communityProperties/propertyowner", . . . 
.. . 
}
```

}

In CommunityPropertiesDataService.java I have

```
import . . . .

@Service
public class CommunityPropertiesDataService{
@Inject 
CommunityPropertyRepository communityPropertiesRepository;

public CommunityProperities create(. . . ){
. . . 
}

public CommunityProperties getCommunityPropertiesById(. . . ){
. . . 
}

public Page<CommunityProperties> getAll(. . . ){
. . . 
}

. . . .
```

}

There is a community-properties.service.js which I have

```
'use strict';
angular.module('communitypropertiesApp').factory('CommunityProperty',function($resource){
return $resource('/rest/api/communityProperties/:id',{},{
'query': { method: 'GET',
transformResponse: function (data){
data = angular.fromJson(data);
return data;
}},


'get': {
method: 'GET',
transformResponse: function (data){
data=angular.fromJson(data);
return data;
}
},  
. . . 
}),
});
```

I added to this file:

```
angular.module('communitypropertiesApp').factory('CommunityPropertiesOwner',function($resource){
return $resource('/rest/api/communityProperties/propertyowner"',{},{
'query': { method: 'GET',
transformResponse: function (data){
data = angular.fromJson(data);
return data;
}},

'get': {
method: 'GET',
transformResponse: function (data){
data=angular.fromJson(data);
return data;
}
},
. . . 
}),
});
```

I cannot "hijack" the /communityproperties/ web service or the communityproperties/{id} web service as they are used elsewhere. So I don't know how to add to this to get only the logged in user's properties. What am I missing here?