# How to use a different export in AngularJS & Express?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a MEAN.JS application. The code below is my AngularJS controller, which runs a query to retrieve all articles in my MongoDB database.

> *public/modules/articles/controllers/**articles.client.controller.js***

```
angular.module('articles').controller('ArticlesController', ['$scope', '$location', '$stateParams', 'Authentication', 'Articles',
    function($scope, $location, $stateParams, Authentication, Articles) {
        ...

        // Find a list of Articles
        this.articles = Articles.query();

        ...
    }
]);
```

The query above is defined in the file and code below:

> *app/controllers/**articles.server.controller.js***

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    Article.find().sort('created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

`Articles.query()` seems to be linked to `exports.list`. I want `Articles.query()` to use a **different** export, let's say `exports.anotherList`. How do I change this?

I have a feeling I have to define it somehow in the file `app/routes/articles.server.routes.js`, but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Thanks. I'll accept the answer that helps me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. Like

1. Configure your `Article` Service's query action for a new URL (for details: [Angular Resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)). Then define a route (for details: [Express Routing](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html)) in your `articles.server.routes.js` for that URL like `app.route('/articles/{new-path}').get(articles.anotherList)` and define your functionality in `articles.server.controller.js`.

OR

2. Try to rename `exports.list` to `exports.anotherList` in `app/routes/articles.server.routes.js`

Create a new function in `articles.server.controller.js` like

```
exports.anotherList = function(req, res) {
    //Write your instructions here
};
```

**There can be other ways. Do what ever you like**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I went with your first method and I got it working now. In case anyone else has a similar question and doesn't know how to add multiple Service routes in AngularJS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160771/angularjs-a-service-that-serves-multiple-resource-urls-data-sources