# Multiple functions in service not allowing for module creation

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I have a CRUD module `activities` instead of the default `articles` but the structure of the module is the same.

When I select to go to the page where I create a new `activity`, `activities.create` state is invoked *(like the `articles` one)*

```
.state('activities.create', {
    url: '/create',
    templateUrl: 'modules/activities/client/views/form-activity.client.view.html',
    controller: 'ActivitiesController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        activityResolve: newActivity
    },
    data: {
        roles: ['user', 'admin'],
        pageTitle: 'Activities Create'
    }
})

function newActivity(ActivitiesService) {
    return new ActivitiesService().getActivitiesOfAllUsers();
}
```

And my `ActivitiesService` looks like this:

```
function ActivitiesService($resource, Authentication) {
    return {
        getActivitiesOfCurrentUser: function() {
            return $resource('api/:userId/activities/:activityId', {
                userId: Authentication.user._id,
                activityId: '@_id'
            }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            });
        },
        getActivitiesOfAllUsers: function() {
            return $resource('api/activities/:activityId', {
                activityId: '@_id'
            }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The default setup the `ActivitiesService` was:

```
function ActivitiesService($resource, Authentication) {
    return $resource('api/:userId/activities/:activityId', {
        userId: Authentication.user._id,
        activityId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
```

And the `newActivity` function would look like this:

```
function newActivity(ActivitiesService) {
    return new ActivitiesService();
}
```

So when the service is in the default layout, going to the create page works just fine.

However, adding another function to the service as I have done is breaking it. When I select to go to the create page, there are no errors and no indications anywhere as to why nothing is happening.

From what I can see, the `activityResolve` should evaluate the same and I cannot figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160771/angularjs-a-service-that-serves-multiple-resource-urls-data-sources#17163459), I found the answer. I amended the `ActivitiesService` to this:

```
function ActivitiesService($resource, Authentication) {
    return {
        getActivitiesOfCurrentUser: $resource('api/:userId/activities/:activityId', {
                userId: Authentication.user._id,
                activityId: '@_id'
            }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            }),
        getActivitiesOfAllUsers: $resource('api/activities/:activityId', {
                activityId: '@_id'
            }, {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            })
    };
}
```

And changed the `newActivity` function to:

```
function newActivity(ActivitiesService) {
    return new ActivitiesService.getActivitiesOfAllUsers;
}
```

*(so without the parentheses on `ActivitiesService`)*